# Power Apps: Ability to use set preferred values to a drop down selection/Radio button

Tags: sharepoint, radio-button, dropdown, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am trying to create a editable form in power apps to collect responses for few questions and save the response data to a SharePoint list. Mostly yes/no questions and preferred using Radio button. I know that I can set a common default value as Yes/No to everyone for question. But I am wondering if there is a way that I can allow the users to set their own default values. Just like preferences and be able to modify when they need

Workarounds Highly Appreciated!!!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are able to set custom pre-sets for a specific user by using a separate lookup List (can be SharePoint). This list will house the user information and the preferred radio button setting for each question.

Example Lookup table columns (we will call it **UserPrefList**):

```
UserObject | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | etc
```

1. Load this table into the app
2. OnVisible of the form, lookup the user accessing and save preferences in a variable. You can also add a default profile if the user has no saved preferences (using IsBlank).

   Set(VarUserPref,LookUp(**UserPrefList**,user().Email = UserObject.Email));
3. On the question radio's, you can now set the default to:

   VarUserPref.Q1
   VarUserPref.Q2
   VarUserPref.Q3
   ...

To allow user to update their preferences, you can add a "Save Preference" button that will update this record in the list. Or if user is new, create one for them.